# LiveData is passing null to observer

Tags: kotlin, android-room, android-livedata

I have the following code

```
myViewModel.catLiveData.observe(this,Observer{
  if(it==null){
      Log.d(TAG,"the object returned is null! How is that possible?")
  }else{ doWork(it) }
})
```

How is it possible that I am getting null? I thought LiveData is not supposed to pass null to the observer? This LiveData is listening to Room Entity, by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LiveData` definitely allows `null` to be sent through to the observers if it's specifically posted. You can see that the method signature for `android.arch.lifecycle.Observer.onChanged` explicitly marks the data parameter as `@Nullable`.

If you don't wish to handle a null type, you can simply use the `?` operator to safely handle it:

```
myViewModel.catLiveData.observe(this, Observer { it?.let(::doWork) })
```

Alternatively, you could create your own custom `Observer` that handles it for you, e.g.

```
class Observer2<T>(private val block: (T) -> Unit) : Observer<T> {
    override fun onChanged(data: T?) {
        data?.let(block)
    }
}
```

Which would allow you to write:

```
myViewModel.catLiveData.observe(this, Observer2(::doWork))
```

Comment: But I thought room would never return a null object to LiveData observers? It is a very typical use case where I have a Room dao return a LiveData for a query. Here is the query in fact: `@Query("SELECT * FROM cats LIMIT 1")`

Comment: I can't speak to the Room library specifically, but perhaps the `LIMIT 1` causes it to return a "Cat" rather than a list of cats? Not sure what the implied type of `it` is in your use case. If that's the case though, then I would think it may be normal to get a null initial value if it returns no result. Looking at the overview [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#use_livedata_with_room), I don't see any indication that a non-null value is guaranteed -- instead all of the observers declare the parameter type as nullable.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the first time Room returns, if there is nothing, then it's null.